# MySQL Workbench Error hover tooltips are blank

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, archlinux

Has anyone else encountered the following issue on the Linux Version of MySQL Workbench?

The tooltip for any error displays a blank rectangle instead of the actual error text.

I have searched the bug tracker for MySQL Workbench, Stackoverflow and a bunch of forums but have not seen anyone come upon this too.

I am using Arch Linux, kernel 5.4.82-1-lts, my DE is xfce4, and I am using the package `mysql-workbench` from the AUR.

Any ideas?

(below is a screenshot of the behavior of the program)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04

I were using a Dark theme

Switching themes from Dark to Standard and then relaunching MySQL workbench did solve the problem